# How to initialize msvcrt.dll?

Tags: c++, winapi, msvcrt

If I do a LoadLibrary("msvcrt.dll") do I need to initialize the CRT somehow? Section 2 in the following document seems to say that I do, but I just get an undefined symbol error for _CRT_INIT when I try to call _CRT_INIT:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/94248

Edit: I should have said that this is for a program that dynamically loads all the dlls that it uses, hence the call to LoadLibrary("msvcrt.dll").

Comment: Why are you doing this?  If you linked to it, it will load automatically.

Comment: Regardless of your edit, why would you explicitly load MSVCRT.DLL rather than simply linking the export library?  Does your app only *sometimes* need the standard library?

Comment: LoadLibrary wil call the dll's entrypoint (DllMain(...)) for you. So you do not need to initialize them further (it's being done automaticcally)

Comment: @Clifford: yes! We want to load it, use it, unload it.

Comment: @Edwin: If you load msvcrt.dll statically, the call sequence is DllMainCRTStartup->_CRT_INT->DllMain. If you load it dynamically (using LoadLibrary) then DllMainCRTStartup (which is CRT specific) is not called. Neither is _CRT_INT.

Comment: @glen: If you avoid CRT_INIT() doesn't it works ? (have you tried it ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working in C++, have you declared `_CRT_INIT` as `extern "C"`?

Have you tried using the `DUMPBIN` utility ( http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177429 -- if you haven't your `PATH` up yourself, you'll have to use the Visual Studio Command Prompt I think) with the `/EXPORTS` switch to see which functions are available from the CRT DLL, just to double check?

If you get stuck, VS2005 and earlier (and presumably later...) come supplied with the source code for the runtime library. For VS2005, this is in `VC/crt/src`, relative to the VS install folder. It looks like `_CRT_INIT` is the right name -- see `crtdll.c` and `dllcrt0.c`, and it's a C function.

Comment: By the way, at the risk of being really annoying or supplying information that I can't tell is inappropriate, I've simply always statically linked with the runtime. Doesn't remove all dependencies on DLLs, but it gets rid of all the ones that tend to cause problems. (I must admit that your problem is one that the CRT DLL has yet to trouble me with though.)

Comment: Hoorah! extern "C" solved it. Now when we step through the LoadLibrary call in the exe to the start of our DLL code, and our DLL calls _CRT_INT, that call (to _CRT_INT) steps into _CRT_INIT in "VC\crt\src\crtdll.c", which you also mentioned!

Answer (score 4):

Call `DllMain()` in it.  If it relies on the C runtime, it will call CRT_INIT.

But a far better question is if a program is using something in msvcrt, there's no need to explicitly load the dll and initialize it, so why are you doing this?

Comment: If msvcrt.dll is statically loaded then DllMain is called by DllMainCRTStartup. DllMainCRTStartup also calls _CRT_INIT. The problem is, because msvcrt.dll is being loaded dynamically DllMainCRTStartup is not there...

Answer (score 0):

You must not call **_CRT_INIT()** but call **CRT_INIT()** (if you really must)

Comment: maybe you need parameters CRT_INIT( hinstDLL, fdwReason, lpReserved );

Comment: The problem isn't the args, because I already use _CRT_INIT(hinstDLL, fdwReason, lpReserved), the problem is that the linker can't find _CRT_INIT (or CRT_INIT), nor does it exist in msvcrt.dll for me to call via GetProcAddress.

Answer (score 0):

The link you referenced refers to using CRT_INIT() only when ***"Using the CRT Libraries When Building a DLL"***, and even then it is only one of two alternatives; the first probably being preferable in most cases.

Comment: If you search the linked page for "if you ***do*** have your own DLL entry point", that is the code we need to insert for our particular situation (2a thru 2d). _CRT_INIT is not found when we do as they say under 2a to 2d.